# Multiple SQL imported by PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In the below code, how would I be able make it look for ALL .sql files in a directory to be read and imported?

```
<?php
$mysqlDatabaseName ='db123456789';
$mysqlUserName ='dbo123456789';
$mysqlPassword ='yourPassword';
$mysqlHostName ='db1234.oneandone.co.uk';
$mysqlImportFilename ='yourMysqlBackupFile.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: By usings phps file (folder) handling functions you find listed in the php documentation.

Comment: Example how I would use this in my code? I have                       `<?php
    foreach (glob("mysqls/*.sql") as $filename)
{ 
 include $filename;
}
 ?>`

Comment: Looks fine, except that of course there is little sense in including an sql file into a php file. Instead put your execution routines inside the foreach loop and feed it with one file at a time. So instead of using the statically defined `$mysqlImportFilename` as file to be executed, use the dynamical ones in each iteration of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I coded the suggestion from the comments I gave. Note: I did not test this code, so there might be some small hickups like typos inside which you have to correct. but it should work in general:

```
<?php
$mysqlDatabaseName = 'db123456789';
$mysqlUserName     = 'dbo123456789';
$mysqlPassword     = 'yourPassword';
$mysqlHostName     = 'db1234.oneandone.co.uk';
$sqlFileMask       = 'mysqls/*.sql';

// prepare the mysql command to be executed per file below
$command = sprintf('mysql -h %s -u %s -p %s %s',
                   $mysqlHostName, 
                   $mysqlUserName, 
                   $mysqlPassword, 
                   $mysqlDatabaseName);

// export the database and output the status to the page
foreach (glob($sqlFileMask) as $filename) {
    exec($command.' < '.$filename, $output=array(), $worked);
    switch($worked) {
        case 0:
            echo "Imported file '$filename' successfully.";
            break;
        default:
            // you should actually consult the exact return value here...
            echo "There was an error during import of file filename'.";
            break;
    } // switch
} // foreach

?>
```

Other hints for you:

- implement more and better error handling
- turn the initial variable initializations into constants
- move the configuration into a separate file
- extra points: include that file by the http server configuration, no by an include command

Comment: Hi I've got a config.php file all set up, how would I make the code work with it and in PDO?

Comment: You cannot use PDO in this. PDO is of use when you execute sql statements from within php using a mysql driver/gateway. You don't do that, you use the command line mysql client instead. But I don't see any reasons to use PDO here anyway, since you do not have direct user input that becomes part of the sql statements as far as I can see.

Comment: About the config file: you either include it using phps include or require commands, or, much more elegant, you have php include that config file by using the `php_admin_value` command inside the http servers vhost section like this: `php_admin_value` auto_prepend_file /path/to/config.php`.

Comment: My whole website is running of PDO queries as well as the PDO database connection. PDO is similar to Mysql, its an extention. Although in the future Mysql is being removed of php 5.0

Comment: MySQL is not removed from php :-) What you mean is: the 'mysql extension' is removed from php, it has been deprecated for years now. There is the more modern 'mysqli extension' that is used these days, it serves similar goals as PDO does. However maybe you did not realize, but with the code you posted you do _not_ use phps mysql extension at all! You use the command line client mysql offers. That has nothing to do with php. mysqli or PDO makes sense to use "prepared statements" where interactive input is used directly inside sql statements. You do not do that, so there is no reason to use PDO.

Comment: Oh my bad. Anyhow i try and use this code, but it comes up with a blank white page. Looked over for errors.. nothing..

Comment: And how can I get it to work with my config.php file?

Comment: I answered your question about your config file above. Please read my comments.

Comment: oh dont worry, thanks. It'll be included automaticly anyways. Anyhow about the white screen problem? Can you make sure the code is fine? I cant personally find a error with it, but its causing a white screen so..

Comment: About your problem to run this code: as said I did not test it, there might be small glitches in it. If you do not get any output, then take a look at the error log file. You have to do that anyway if you are developing php code. If that does not help, then use a debugger and step through the code. You have to do that anyway if you are trying to develop code of good quality.

Comment: The code looks fine on a short inspection. Most likely you do _not_ have any sql files in that folder `mysqls` you specified.